# How to interchange tabBar items in UITabBarController in Swift

Tags: swift3

On Specific condition, I want to exchange tabBar item at index 1 with tabBar item at index 6. So that tabBar item at index 6 will appear on index 1 and tabBar item at index 1 will appear on index 6. How will I do this?